# Elasticsearch sorting not working properly based on time

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have 20 documents and i'm performing aggregation based on reportid. I need top 10 aggregation based on time in descending. But the response is very random. What am i missing? I'm using elasticsearch 6.2.2 and node.js 4.5. Below here is the body search query for elasticsearch request.

```
{
"size": 0,
"sort": [
{
    "triggerDate":
    {
        "order": "desc"
    }
}],
"query":
{
    "bool":
    {
        "must": [
            {
                "query_string":
                {
                    "query": "*",
                    "analyze_wildcard": true
                }
            },

            {
                "range":
                {
                    "triggerDate":
                    {
                        "gte": fromTime,
                        "lte": toTime
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "must_not": [
        {
            "query_string":
            {
                "query": "reportId.keyword:\"\"",
                "analyze_wildcard": true
            }
        }]
    }
},
"_source":
{
    "excludes": []
},
"aggs":
{
    "reportid":
    {
        "terms":
        {
            "field": "reportId.keyword",
            "size": 10
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you're returning are not documents (i.e. size=0) but aggregations terms. The `sort` clause is only useful in the context of the hits, not the aggregations. Aggregations are not returning documents, only terms.

Comment: Thanks. But how can i fix this issue?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve... Maybe show a sample response and how it diverges from what you'd like

Comment: As val mentioned, more clarity is needed on what do you want per agg bucket like what agg function should be applied on `triggerDate` per bucket?

Comment: I'm grouping up documents based on an id. Lets say i have 20 aggregations. All those aggregations has a time field name **triggeredDate**. I need to get top 10 hits based on ** triggeredDate**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need to do is aggregate on reportId.keyword and sort aggregation by date.

So here is the solution

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*",
            "analyze_wildcard": true
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "triggerDate": {
              "gte": fromTime,
              "lte": toTime
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "reportId.keyword:\"\"",
            "analyze_wildcard": true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "_source": {
    "excludes": []
  },
  "aggs": {
    "reportid": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "reportId.keyword",
        "size": 10,
        "order": {
          "2-orderAgg": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "2-orderAgg": {
          "max": {
            "field": "triggerDate"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You need to sort the aggregation results by a custom aggregation and not the query results.